# CSS in jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have confusion in using the CSS in jQuery [**DataTable**](http://datatables.net). They had provided many CSS but in example they used only 1 or 2.  [**(DataTable Download)**](http://datatables.net/download)

So my question is what are the uses or difference of this css in datatable. I searched it, but i didn't get relevant answer.

```
 1. demo_page                     // ?
 2. demo_table                    // ?
 3. demo_table_jui                // ?
 4. jquery.dataTables             // ?
 5. jquery.dataTables_themeroller // To include jQuery UI theme.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want to use only basic style as datables.net's examples, you
  can use `4.jquery.dataTables.css`.
- If you want to use jquery ui, you can include `3.demo_table_jui.css` - this is jquery ui smoothness theme, light grey color.

  (if your site has already included jquery ui css file from jqueryui.com,  no need to use `3.demo_table_jui.css`).
- If you want to change style on the fly using jquery themeroller (like http://www.datatables.net/styling/themes), also include `5.jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css`.
- You can leave `1.demo_page` and `2.demo_table`, they are only for demo table styles.

#### This css files has also its description on the top of the file.

Comment: `2.demo_table.css` have more class or options than `4.jquery.dataTables.css` like sorting, grade. So can i use `2.demo_table` instead of `4.jquery.dataTables.css` ? and all feature of `4.jquery.dataTables.css` included in `2.demo_table`?

Comment: for me, I only pick the styles that I want :) such as sorting, tabletools, DTTT_container,... not all their files.

Comment: I want to change the records per page to only records or wanna put a `<br>` tag between records per page and search. how can i do this. and Instead of search text label I would like to place a placeholder inside the search text box. Is it possible in datatables

Comment: late reply, pls try this... $(".scrollTable").dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {"sSearch": ""}
    });
    $(".dataTables_filter input").attr("placeholder","Search anything...");